# Difference between ~= and ~<> tags in wis file

Tags: xml, tags, wix

What is the difference between these two tags `~=` and `~<>` ?

For example:

```
<Condition><![CDATA[CUSTOMER~="xyz"]]></Condition>
```

and

```
<Condition><![CDATA[CUSTOMER~<>"abc"]]></Condition>
```

What exactly is happening in above two conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Conditional Statement Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa368012.aspx)

> For string comparisons, a tilde "~" prefixed to the operator performs a comparison that is not case sensitive.
>
> = TRUE if left value is equal to right value.
>
> <>    TRUE if left value is not equal to right value.

So the first one is a case-insensitive equal and the second a case-insensitive not equal.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :), I have one doubt though.
Does the exclamatory mark ! before the CDATA, can impact the condition?

Comment: No, that is not a condition, that is just the format for a CDATA see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean